# jboss cli for modifying default-workmanager

Tags: java, jboss, command-line-interface

Subsystem in question is :

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:1.1">
<archive-validation enabled="true" fail-on-error="true" fail-on-warn="false"/>
<bean-validation enabled="true"/>
<default-workmanager>
 <short-running-threads>
  <core-threads count="50"/>
  <queue-length count="50"/>
  <max-threads count="50"/>
  <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
 </short-running-threads>
 <long-running-threads>
  <core-threads count="50"/>
  <queue-length count="50"/>
  <max-threads count="50"/>
  <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
 </long-running-threads>
</default-workmanager>
<cached-connection-manager/>
</subsystem>
```

I want to modify 3 properties : core-threads count, queue-length count and max-threads count under both `<short-running-threads>` and `<long-running-threads>` using jboss cli.

Can anyone please provide the cli to modify these properties ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to change the defaults, not the counts. Counters are actual values used for monitoring, not intended to be set.

Try with `jboss-cli` within the JBoss `bin` directory.

1.) Call `./jboss-cli.sh -c`. The CLI supports context sensitive command completion on every part of the command.

or

2.) Call `./jboss-cli.sh --gui`. Use the GUI to navigate to the JCA subsystem down to the needed attribute. You can change it with one mouse click using the `write-attribute` context menu entry. After setting the new value, the matching CLI command is shown in a textfield on top of the GUI, ready for copy/paste.

This is an example for setting a default value:

```
/subsystem=jca/workmanager=default/long-running-threads=default/:write-attribute(name=core-threads,value=200)
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Frito suggested our final cli looks like below :

```
# Batch script to modify thread count configuration in the JBoss server

# Connect to JBoss
connect

# Start batching commands
batch

#Modify short-running-threads
/subsystem=jca/workmanager=default/short-running-threads=default/:write-attribute(name=core-threads,value=200)
/subsystem=jca/workmanager=default/short-running-threads=default/:write-attribute(name=queue-length,value=200)
/subsystem=jca/workmanager=default/short-running-threads=default/:write-attribute(name=max-threads,value=200)

#Modify long-running-threads
/subsystem=jca/workmanager=default/long-running-threads=default/:write-attribute(name=core-threads,value=200)
/subsystem=jca/workmanager=default/long-running-threads=default/:write-attribute(name=queue-length,value=200)
/subsystem=jca/workmanager=default/long-running-threads=default/:write-attribute(name=max-threads,value=200)

# Reload to appy changes
:reload

# Run the batch commands
run-batch
```

Standalone.xml snippet after executing the cli :

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:1.1">
<archive-validation enabled="true" fail-on-error="true" fail-on-warn="false"/>
<bean-validation enabled="true"/>
<default-workmanager>
 <short-running-threads>
  <core-threads count="200"/>
  <queue-length count="200"/>
  <max-threads count="200"/>
  <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
 </short-running-threads>
 <long-running-threads>
  <core-threads count="200"/>
  <queue-length count="200"/>
  <max-threads count="200"/>
  <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
 </long-running-rhreads>
</default-workmanager>
<cached-connection-manager/>
</subsystem>
```